# How do i convert to a number in sqllite or sqlalchemy in python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

i have encoded image and i want to store it in a database

the  encoded image looks like

```
[array([-0.06772001,  0.05728862, -0.0251427 , -0.08454875, -0.03213117,
       -0.03106732,  0.00076004, -0.06710728,  0.13713066, -0.11327504,
        0.21360487, -0.09900057, -0.22535393, -0.05674654, -0.0756731 ,
        0.05203095, -0.15146038, -0.0874744 , -0.10700339, -0.06584571,
        0.07124957,  0.04297648,  0.00613243,  0.10702223, -0.18388851,
       -0.29916996, -0.02585445, -0.10655323,  0.02479932, -0.1107952 ,
        0.05695343,  0.15145421, -0.14358994,  0.01052327, -0.04699658,
        0.05112756, -0.01958742, -0.13124494,  0.22351149,  0.08037129,
       -0.14257275, -0.00716499, -0.04201137,  0.30405453,  0.09107384,
       -0.02807541,  0.06258672, -0.05632804,  0.1744605 , -0.22389032,
       -0.00614528,  0.19390592,  0.13520201,  0.02655653,  0.05437692,
       -0.12989879,  0.11905471,  0.167327  , -0.2371735 ,  0.0535943 ,
        0.02655954, -0.02821845,  0.00393433, -0.01588794,  0.08551847,
        0.05382346, -0.08446158, -0.04891751,  0.13232884, -0.11974856,
       -0.01156278,  0.1275105 , -0.10302921, -0.28067535, -0.13956669,
        0.08966827,  0.35788029,  0.2560949 , -0.15698224,  0.00970889,
       -0.05089435, -0.03781725,  0.13893284,  0.06806683, -0.11791685,
       -0.06655203, -0.1322563 ,  0.05103128,  0.14470096,  0.0419168 ,
       -0.06990704,  0.22407535,  0.0648756 , -0.07097621,  0.008138  ,
       -0.0258901 , -0.16763684,  0.09151821, -0.0178766 ,  0.02473853,
        0.10130395, -0.08122514, -0.0450197 ,  0.05235555, -0.154888  ,
        0.19613147, -0.02572119, -0.06538303,  0.01294655, -0.03529175,
       -0.05470725,  0.00442413,  0.09804396, -0.23483986,  0.05548284,
        0.13926584,  0.07040435,  0.21667242,  0.07278855,  0.06018258,
        0.02701348, -0.04436196, -0.16826543, -0.12570928,  0.11218779,
        0.02221176,  0.04686672, -0.07655797])]
```

but when i view or select * from the database the output is something like this

```
(b"\x00\x00\x00@\x19V\xb1\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\xefT\xad?\x00\x00\x00@\x02\xbf\x99\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xa0\xfc\xa4\xb5\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x7fs\xa0\xbf\x00\x00\x00`\x1c\xd0\x9f\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\xac\xe7H?\x00\x00\x00@\xf1-\xb1\xbf\x00\x00\x00`\x7f\x8d\xc1?\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x97\xff\xbc\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x80gW\xcb?\x00\x00\x00\xe0\x19X\xb9\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc0e\xd8\xcc\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xe1\r\xad\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00P_\xb3\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xcc\xa3\xaa?\x00\x00\x00\xc0\rc\xc3\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xb8d\xb6\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x93d\xbb\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xa0C\xdb\xb0\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x80i=\xb2?\x00\x00\x00\x80\x03\x01\xa6?\x00\x00\x00\xc0Q\x1ey?\x00\x00\x00 \xcfe\xbb?\x00\x00\x00\xa0\xa8\x89\xc7\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x99%\xd3\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x97y\x9a\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x80\x12G\xbb\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x80\xfed\x99?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13]\xbc\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00)\xad?\x00\x00\x00\x00\xdab\xc3?\x00\x00\x00\xc0'a\xc2\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc08\x8d\x85?\x00\x00\x00\x80\xef\x0f\xa8\xbf\x00\x00\x00`d-\xaa?\x00\x00\x00\x80\xb9\x0e\x94\xbf\x00\x00\x00`\xa2\xcc\xc0\xbf\x00\x00\x00@\x06\x9c\xcc?\x00\x00\x00\x806\x93\xb4?\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xd2?\xc2\xbf\x00\x00\x00@\x08Y}\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x83\x82\xa5\xbf\x00\x00\x00 \xa1u\xd3?\x00\x00\x00\x80\x9dP\xb7?\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xcc\xbf\x9c\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\xaf\x05\xb0?\x00\x00\x00@\x07\xd7\xac\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xb8T\xc6?\x00\x00\x00 p\xa8\xcc\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\xca+y\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xe8\xd1\xc8?\x00\x00\x00\xa0LN\xc1?\x00\x00\x00@\xa21\x9b?\x00\x00\x00\xc0J\xd7\xab?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x86\xa0\xc0\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xa0^z\xbe?\x00\x00\x00\xa0\xf8j\xc5?\x00\x00\x00\x80\xb3[\xce\xbf\x00\x00\x00@\xb6p\xab?\x00\x00\x00\x80l2\x9b?\x00\x00\x00\xe0K\xe5\x9c\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x80p\x1dp?\x00\x00\x00\x80\xedD\x90\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xe0\x89\xe4\xb5?\x00\x00\x00\xa0\xbf\x8e\xab?\x00\x00\x00@F\x9f\xb5\xbf\x00\x00\x00@\xb7\x0b\xa9\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc0&\xf0\xc0?\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7\xa7\xbe\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00:\xae\x87\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xa0CR\xc0?\x00\x00\x00@\x1f`\xba\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x95\xf6\xd1\xbf\x00\x00\x00@R\xdd\xc1\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xf4\xb6?\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x82\xe7\xd6?\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xdbc\xd0?\x00\x00\x00\x80\xfe\x17\xc4\xbf\x00\x00\x00 A\xe2\x83?\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xd2\x0e\xaa\xbf\x00\x00\x00`\xc8\\\xa3\xbf\x00\x00\x00 \x8d\xc8\xc1?\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xd3l\xb1?\x00\x00\x00\x80\xcc/\xbe\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x8d\t\xb1\xbf\x00\x00\x00@\xc6\xed\xc0\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x80\xc5 \xaa?\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x8f\x85\xc2?\x00\x00\x00\x80\x1ev\xa5?\x00\x00\x00\x80m\xe5\xb1\xbf\x00\x00\x00@\x80\xae\xcc?\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xaf\x9b\xb0?\x00\x00\x00@\x7f+\xb2\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x80\xa7\xaa\x80?\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xee\x82\x9a\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x1fu\xc5\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xbcm\xb7?\x00\x00\x00@>N\x92\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x80\x0eU\x99?\x00\x00\x00@\x0e\xef\xb9?\x00\x00\x00\xc0+\xcb\xb4\xbf\x00\x00\x00`\xd2\x0c\xa7\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc0X\xce\xaa?\x00\x00\x00\xc0^\xd3\xc3\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd6\x1a\xc9?\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xa7V\x9a\xbf\x00\x00\x00@\xf1\xbc\xb0\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xa0\xb8\x83\x8a?\x00\x00\x00\x80\xc2\x11\xa2\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x96\x02\xac\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x1fr?\x00\x00\x00\xa0h\x19\xb9?\x00\x00\x00\x80;\x0f\xce\xbf\x00\x00\x00@?h\xac?\x00\x00\x00\x80v\xd3\xc1?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x06\xb2?\x00\x00\x00\x00\xec\xbb\xcb?\x00\x00\x00@E\xa2\xb2?\x00\x00\x00`@\xd0\xae?\x00\x00\x00\xa0k\xa9\x9b?\x00\x00\x00\x80\x9c\xb6\xa6\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc0\xb8\x89\xc5\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xe0=\x17\xc0\xbf\x00\x00\x00\xc0V\xb8\xbc?\x00\x00\x00\x00\xae\xbe\x96?\x00\x00\x00@\xea\xfe\xa7?\x00\x00\x00\xa0M\x99\xb3\xbf",)
```

i did that by two different codes and the result is the same

code nom1

```
x=face_recognition.face_encodings(new_picture)
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///image.db', echo = True)
meta = MetaData()

img= Table(
   'img', meta, 
   Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True), 
   Column('imagecode', String), 
   
)
meta.create_all(engine)
engine.execute("insert into students  (name) values (?)",(x,))
```

code nom2

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('image.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS img(keyword TEXT)")                       
c.execute("insert into image(imagecode) values (?)",(x))
conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

So how can i convert it to original image code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store an object like that you should serialize it and store it as a BLOB (Binary Large OBject):

```py
import array
import pickle
import sqlite3

cnxn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute("CREATE TABLE image (id int primary key, imagecode varbinary)")

original = [array.array("d", [-0.123, -0.456])]
sql = "INSERT INTO image (id, imagecode) VALUES (1, ?)"
params = (pickle.dumps(original), )
crsr.execute(sql, params)

sql = "SELECT imagecode FROM image WHERE id = 1"
retrieved = pickle.loads(crsr.execute(sql).fetchone()[0])
print(retrieved)  # [array('d', [-0.123, -0.456])]
```

Comment: can you explain what is this part original = [array.array("d", [-0.123, -0.456])]

Comment: Your question said that the "thing' you were trying to save was a list that contained a single `array` object. That statement creates such a "thing" and stores it in a variable named `original`.

Comment: so what is this stands for ("d", [-0.123, -0.456])]

Comment: x is encoded pic (x=face_recognition.face_encodings(new_picture)) but i don't know where to but i it in your code can you help me ?

Comment: Try `params = (pickle.dumps(x), )`

Comment: it only returns first one i have five records in database how can i show all of them?

Comment: it only returns first one i have five records in database how can i show all of them?

Comment: when i do retrieved = pickle.loads(c.execute(sql).fetchone()[1]) it says IndexError: tuple index out of range, although i have five records.